# Xcode variables

Tags: xcode, variables, build-process, build-automation

In Xcode, I know that you can get variables such as `PROJECT_DIR` to use in some situations, such as a run script build phase. I am wondering if it's possible to get the build type (i.e., *Release* or *Debug*). Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Canonical list of Xcode Environment Variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6910901/canonical-list-of-xcode-environment-variables)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I print a list of "Build Settings" in Xcode project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6910901/how-do-i-print-a-list-of-build-settings-in-xcode-project)

Answer (score 160, accepted):

The best source is probably [Apple's official documentation](http://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/8.0/#/itcaec37c2a6). The specific variable you are looking for is CONFIGURATION.

Comment: I love the way that Xcode refuses to show that page if you type in "build settings" in a search box - you get the OTHER kind of build setting, with no reference to these variables. Ditto if you put "build variables". Someone should teach Apple how to write a search algorithm :)

Comment: If you're trying to create a "run script build phase", you can start off this script by typing "env" (without the quotes) as the first line of your bash shell script (or the equivalent command for the shell you're using) and build your project. This will output all of the environment variables that are available to you. You can use this in conjunction with the documentation to make sure you're getting the data that you expected.

Comment: I think I've wasted half an hour trying to find the docs listing/explaining environment variables available to scripts.  I submitted an "enhancement" request asking why they can't just put one of those round question-mark buttons in there with a link to the proper help page.  Great suggestion HZC, though I wish it wasn't necessary.

Comment: I cannot find a var usable to tell if I am building for simulator/device. e.g /$CONFIGURATION/$SDK. SDK_ROOT is close but I want a var which maps directly to the xcode options for iOS development, simulator|device

Comment: Also sad that the basic $PROJECT_DIR is not mentioned anywhere in that official document. I guess it's just a (better named) alias for $SRCROOT.

Comment: The link is broken

Comment: Apple likes to periodically rearrange all of their documentation and break all existing links. Someone will have to hunt down the new link.

Answer (score 24):

[Here's a list of the environment variables](http://maxao.free.fr/xcode-plugin-interface/build-settings.html#variables). I think you might want `CURRENT_VARIANT`. See also `BUILD_VARIANTS`.

Comment: Ok, so when I use char* cv = getenv("CURRENT_VARIANT"); I get NULL. What am I missing?

Comment: The other answer is right. This isn't.  CONFIGURATION is what they want.

Comment: And that's not even the full list ... half the truth

Answer (score 9):

They're not **all** documented. For example, you won't find `ARCHIVE_PATH`, `MARKETING_VERSION` (the version string set in Xcode) in Naaff's  or smorgan's answer. These 2 are very common pieces of information someone would need! Here's a list of all of them I got: https://gist.github.com/ben-xD/c063b0ca2c33684de1eb379bb9d6405d

### How I got them

**I found the best way was to print them** using `set`, I just wrote [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66852827/is-there-an-environment-variable-for-the-archive-directory-in-xcode) including a method to list all the environment variables available.

Add this to your run script (either Archive post run script, or your build phases run script, etc.):

```sh
#!/bin/sh
exec > ${PROJECT_DIR}/environment_variables.log 2>&1
set
```

Look in `environment_variables.log` and you'll see them all.