# Not able to run doxygen script through my xcode?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, doxygen, documentation-generation

I have installed doxygen.dmg. I have used this link for reference: [duckrowing](http://www.duckrowing.com/2010/03/18/documenting-objective-c-with-doxygen-part-ii/)

I have followed each and every step from that. Now I am able to create html docset using that doxygen tool. But for the next steps, while generating a documentation using XCode itself using some script phase. I have tried that also but it throws me error while building that application. Here is the error:

.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/.build/loadDocSet.scpt:23:157: execution error: Xcode got an error: No documentation set present at specified path. (6)

Please help me for that. I want to generate my documentation on build phase only.

So that it can be automatically changed if i change my code.

Thanks in advance.

Mrunal

Comment: In case you don't know appledoc: http://www.gentlebytes.com/home/appledocapp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It probably means that Xcode's working directory isn't your source trees directory.

Trace the working directory with a `pwd` in the script to prove this.

Use  `pushd \foo\bar\myproject\` and `popd` to bracket your call to doxygen. As in

```
pushd \Users\mrunal\projects\fooproject\
doxygen -switch -blah 
popd
```

You might even get away with a simple `cd \foo\bar\myproject\` at the start but don't be surprised if this borks the rest of the build.

or use one of the doxygen command switches to explicitly define the working directory. I don't have it installed at the moment but most likely `-d` or `-w`

There is also an environment variable to dynamically define the source directory. so you could do `cd $PROJECT_DIR`

See [Xcode variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/890569/xcode-variables) for lots more environ vars

Comment: Hi Warren, can you please check with the environment variable and let me know? It would be really helpful to me. Thanks for providing info. I am new to use this Doxygen so...