# Is there an environment variable for the Archive directory in Xcode?

Tags: xcode

Is there an environment variable for the Archive directory in Xcode? I wasn't able to find any in the documentation: https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/8.0/#/itcaec37c2a6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### It's called `ARCHIVE_PRODUCTS_PATH` or `ARCHIVE_PATH`, depending on which one you want.

---

### To find out other useful (undocumented?) environment variables:

I made a script to print all the environment variables available during the archive process.

Add this is as a post-action Archive script (Schemes drop down → Edit Scheme... → Archive (expand dropdown) → Post-actions → Run Script → Paste the following:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
exec > ${PROJECT_DIR}/post-archive.log 2>&1
${PROJECT_DIR}/Scripts/print_all_environment_variables.sh
```

Script: (e.g. `print_all_environment_variables.sh`), `set` will print all environment variables

```sh
#!/bin/sh
set
```

Now you can have a look at `post-archive.log` and it will have a bunch of environment variables (more than 1000 lines). The one you're looking for is:

```
ARCHIVE_PRODUCTS_PATH='/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/DATE/Project Name DateTime.xcarchive/Products'
```

or,

```
ARCHIVE_PATH='/Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/DATE/Project Name DateTime.xcarchive'
```

Comment: Can you please take a look at the following question:https://stackoverflow.com/q/66853550/9409877