# MongoDB connection error in Digital Ocean droplet

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, deployment, environment-variables, digital-ocean

I am in the process of deploying my MERN app to a Digital Ocean droplet (Ubuntu 20.04 server).

I have cloned my GitHub repo to the droplet, installed the dependencies using `npm install`. Next, when I am starting the server using `npm start`, I get the following error:
[image]

The error essentially says that the first parameter to `mongoose.connect()` is undefined and must be a string. However, everything works fine in my local machine and when I console.log `process.env.MONGO_URI`, I get the connection string.

server/config/db.js

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const colors = require("colors");
const dotenv = require("dotenv");

dotenv.config();

const connectDB = async () => {
  try {
    const conn = await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI, {
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      useCreateIndex: true,
      useUnifiedTopology: true,
    });
    console.log(`MongoDB connected: ${conn.connection.host}`.cyan.bold);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(`Error: ${error.message}`.red.bold.underline);
    process.exit(1);
  }
};
2;
module.exports = connectDB;
```

Why am I getting this error while starting the server in my Digital Ocean droplet?

Answer (score 1):

`dotenv` doesn't load system variables.

Create `.env` file with

```
MONGO_URI=XXXXXXX
```

https://github.com/motdotla/dotenv#usage

> Create a .env file in the root directory of your project. Add
> environment-specific variables on new lines in the form of NAME=VALUE.
> For example:

```
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_USER=root
DB_PASS=s1mpl3
```

Comment: I have the `.env` file in my root directory and the `MONGO_URI` is available in the file.

Comment: @HKS can cat the file contents to be sure also, also do `console.log(process.env)`

Comment: When I console log `process.env.MONGO_URI` in my local machine, I am getting the connection string that I have defined in the `.env` file. I don't know why `MONGO_URI` is undefined in the droplet.

Comment: @HKS can you check in droplet do you `.env` file ?

Comment: I have placed `.env` in `.gitignore` so that it is not pushed to Github. Oh yeah, I understand where the problem is. `.env` is not available in the droplet. So, what do I do now? I can't push the `.env` file to Github because my keys will be exposed. How do I then bring `.env` file to the droplet?

Comment: @HKS Create `.env` file in your droplet. Login to the server `vim .env` in your code root folder and insert `MONGO_URI` value.

Comment: When I typed `vim .env`, a window opened where I entered my environment variables. Then what? I pressed enter multiple times and the cursor just kept going down. What did I do wrong? I checked the directory, there was no `.env` file.

Comment: Can you please take a look at the following question:https://stackoverflow.com/q/66858780/9409877